# Force.com IDE: Synchronizing with server blocks IDE

Tags: apex, force.com, eclipse

I am developing Apex code using Force.com plugin for Eclipse. When I save changes, synchronization with server begins and blocks the entire IDE. It takes up to 5minutes which is too long. Are there any options to disable blocking the IDE so I could develop more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using MavensMate for Sublime Text for precisely this reason - it runs as a separate application, so no blocking when performing operations.

http://mavensmate.com/

Comment: Do you mean no blocking but staying in sync with the server?

Comment: You can commit and it will go off and deploy the changes, you can pull down and still work on code.